# GWT hosted mode fails loading module but the generated war works elsewhere

Tags: gwt, gxt, gwt-hosted-mode, gwt-maven-plugin

I'm using maven-gwt-plugin and ext-gwt for my GWT project and when I want to run the hosted mode in eclipse as advised here: http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/hosted.html I got the following message:

```
16:47:13.063 [ERROR] [tempoui] Unable to load module entry point class net.stinfoservices.axsens.tempo.ui.client.TempoUI (see associated exception for details)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Deferred binding failed for 'com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.image.XImages' (did you forget to inherit a required module?)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:53)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:98)
    at com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.GXT.<clinit>(GXT.java:37)
    at com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.util.Theme.<clinit>(Theme.java:44)
    at net.stinfoservices.axsens.tempo.ui.client.TempoUI.onModuleLoad(TempoUI.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:396)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:525)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo.JClassType, but class was expected
    at com.google.gwt.user.rebind.ui.ImageBundleGenerator.getValidUserType(ImageBundleGenerator.java:367)
    at com.google.gwt.user.rebind.ui.ImageBundleGenerator.generate(ImageBundleGenerator.java:142)
    at com.google.gwt.core.ext.GeneratorExtWrapper.generate(GeneratorExtWrapper.java:48)
    at com.google.gwt.core.ext.GeneratorExtWrapper.generateIncrementally(GeneratorExtWrapper.java:60)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.StandardGeneratorContext.runGeneratorIncrementally(StandardGeneratorContext.java:647)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.RuleGenerateWith.realize(RuleGenerateWith.java:41)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle$Rebinder.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:78)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:268)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ShellModuleSpaceHost.rebind(ShellModuleSpaceHost.java:141)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebind(ModuleSpace.java:585)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebindAndCreate(ModuleSpace.java:455)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:49)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:98)
    at com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.GXT.<clinit>(GXT.java:37)
    at com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.util.Theme.<clinit>(Theme.java:44)
    at net.stinfoservices.axsens.tempo.ui.client.TempoUI.onModuleLoad(TempoUI.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:396)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:525)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

However, if I `mvn clean install` and put the generated war on an external jetty it works.

I really want to use the hosted mode since it's a gain of development time.

Here is my pom.xml: http://pastebin.com/xPwCkw2c

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong or what is going on?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

The incompatible class change is an indication that you have two different versions of GWT on your classpath - but only at dev mode, not at compile time if the war works. How are you running dev mode? You are using a fairly old version of GWT (and gwt-maven-plugin too) - is it possible that you are trying to run dev mode from your IDE which is including a more recent version of GWT?

The recent breaking changes occurred at GWT 2.0 and GWT 2.2.0. Depending on which copy of GXT you are getting, you might only be compatible with GWT 2.0 until 2.1.x. Newer versions of GXT from http://www.sencha.com/products/extgwt/downloads/ include three jars, one for before GWT 2.0, one for between 2.0 and 2.2, and one for 2.2 and beyond.